# How long do sharkfin melons keep?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, melon

I read somewhere that sharkfin melons ([*Cucurbita ficifolia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita_ficifolia)) keep for years, if kept dry. Is that really true? It seems an awesomely long time. I have some seeds on order, so even if no one else has experience here, I plan to find out.

Comment: FYI: I grew some since I asked this. Mine kept for just over a year. With improved storage conditions, they might have lasted longer. The unripe ones ripened in storage (the seeds even matured). They looked and tasted kind of like tangy rice noodles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely an unusually long-lasting melon, although sources list a few different timeframes.
[Sowing New Seeds](http://www.sowingnewseeds.org.uk/pdfs/Growing%20shark%20fin%20melons.pdf) says

> if kept in a cool, dry, frost-free place, they keep very well for several months, and reportedly over a year.

[The Curious Gardener](http://www.curiousgardener.com/2012/05/29/welcome-shark-fin-melon-plant/) increases that:

> If kept dry after harvest, a fruit can last several years.